# Cusotm Category Select Attribute value not saving

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have created a custom category select attribute to list active categories, after choosing a category from the list and saving there is an error message displayed "attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again" I have checked the values of the selected category it seems like good

---

### ***Category_form.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="category_category_attribute" formElement="select" sortOrder="20">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">xxxx\CustomCategoryAttribute\Model\Config\Source\CustomOptionList</item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Category</label>
                <dataScope>category</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

### Patch file

```
<?php

namespace xxxx\CustomCategoryAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;


class CategoryAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{

    protected $_moduleDataSetup;
    protected $_eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->_moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->_moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Category::ENTITY, 'category_category_attribute', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'category list',
            'input' => 'select',
            'default' => '',
            'source' => 'xxxx\CustomCategoryAttribute\Model\Config\Source\CustomOptionList',
            'sort_order' => 3,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
            'visible_on_front' => true
        ]);
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

---

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="promo_category_category_attribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">
                    xxxx\PromoCategory\Model\Config\Source\PromoCategoryOptionList
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Promo Category</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">promo_category_category_attribute</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">promo_category_category_attribute</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update eav attribute creation code to this and then try

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(Category::ENTITY, 'category_category_attribute', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'category list',
                'input' => 'select',
                'default' => '',
                'source' => 'xxxx\CustomCategoryAttribute\Model\Config\Source\CustomOptionList',
                'sort_order' => 3,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'backend' => '',
                'visible' => 1,
                'required' => 0,
                'user_defined' => 1,
            ]);
```

Comment: required =>0 is not a solution for this , I tried but no changes. when I inspected, I found that the corresponding categories id set on the value of the select UI component but not saving